# How does Cygwin work for python programming?

Tags: javascript, python, django, cygwin

I am currently faced with a dilemma about cygwin. I have only demoed it to see it.  I am wondering about building python into the cygwin install, installing python in windows and symlinking it to cygwin or if it is even efficient to use cygwin to program python. I switched to Ubuntu a couple years ago for my programming needs. Please note: I program for the web using python web frameworks. Django has a built-in dev server as well as sqlite3 which is wonderful for the development stage of a project. Will I be able to use things like Django test server and sqlite3 from cygwin (they are all python so i don't see why not).

The reason it is essential I have a Windows machine: Music Production (driver issues, software), Front-end development and graphic design.

Comment: So..... what are you asking about again?

Comment: This seem to be two entirely unrelated questions. I don't seem to find the connection between the two parts.

Comment: 1. How WELL does it work. My bad. Will it behave just as it does in the Linux environment in terms of functionality. Will it throw me random errors due to being ran through cygwin? etc.. I don't want to start a project in it blindfolded. Will I be able to use modules just the same as I could in *nix.

2. As an after thought I figured I would ask for a solution to the reason I am on a Linux box for some of my dev anyways so that I can just use Linux when I'm doing dev work and Windows when doing audio work.

Comment: @eusid, works fine. The only problem I ran into with cygwin and django `runserver` is vfork resource unavailable errors which I solved by running the dev server through windows python (I set up a windows virtual env). I'd hit the shell and everything else through cygwin simultaneously.

Comment: Thank you Yuji. That is all I wanted. The off-chance I could find something similar to Adobe's live view port and live code view crossed my mind and apparently confused some people. Make this the answer and I will make it the accepted answer. I have changed the question to reflect only the question related to python, cygwin, and django. 

@Yuji Tomita: My next question would be so when you installed cygwin did you install it's Python or did you run your windows python from the cygwin CLI ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a great experience using cygwin on windows.

The major issue I had to solve was that `runserver` is unstable / slow through cygwin due to vfork resource unavailable errors which I researched was not a trivial problem to solve. Runserver is very much noticeably slow in the first place, so this was a major deal breaker for me (attempting to go from osx to windows).

Here is what I did to make my workflow smooth across both cygwin and windows pythons.
http://yuji.wordpress.com/2011/07/18/django-runserver-development-server-is-slow-on-cygwin/

Which python did I use? I don't remember...

You mentioned editors... I use a cross platform editor called sublime text 2. Same for windows and osx. Fantastic.

Adobe's live view port? You don't mean dreamweaver do you? Because that live editor was the worst. You want real browsers to render your code... the same ones real people use.

Besides, if you're developing in django, you need a request/response cycle - can't really go live.

Comment: I can agree that you want real browsers to render your code. Its just there are no other browsers with a live view port. Mostly what I use it for is when doing things with UI. Like a jQuery animation. So I find myself doing the markup with zen-coding. Then going into Photoshop and creating the graphics I need per my layout/decided grid dimensions. After that, going back to DW which isn't hard I'm still on Windoze. Then getting on Linux to do all the back-end (Pythonic/Django). I find this daunting. Windows although Python interpreted did not like me. So I switched to Linux. I just want 1 OS.:)

Comment: Addendum: I'm sure someone has thought of embedding an instance of firefox or chrome viewport into an IDE no? The closest thing I've found is kompozer and it is fantastic except its live view shows you nothing like the browser will and shows nothing active just static renderings. No JS.

Comment: @Eusid, I hear you - that's exactly why I made this windows switch as well. I needed my adobe workflow and couldn't use linux. Then, I switched to OSX. Now I have my adobe workflow, and unix workflow. Done.

Comment: Tomia: If there was a way to emulate OSX other than via Virtual Box or something I would do that. However,  I just can't justify paying that much for the fruit. Asus lives :)  Over the years I have built my own machines and certain companies have proven themselves to me. PSU: Enermax, Cases: Depends, Proc: AMD Memory: Patriot (high performance memory company that always benches equal with corsair for half the price), Motherboards: Asus, Anything built by asus I would put my money on. Gosh the new Asus Transform kills the iPad :) Not trying to start a war, but I'm off topic.

Comment: I have tried Aptana Studio, and Wakanda. Wakanda seems like someone that is going for an almost entirely Javascript based site. I am curious to see where node.js and other emerging js libraries take the web, but I am not ready to switch to them. Aptana does have a nice browser view ++Aptana . I spent too long learning python as a language to make a switch. Sure I do front-end work so I use JS but relying on it for everything with HTML5 etc seems a little creepy to me. Very impressive Ajax/JS site is http://www.anidb.net If you install the app it finds all you have highlights what you have/miss